# CURL get external page cookies and use them in my page

Tags: php, cookies, curl

am trying to get all cookies from external page and set them in my page, i have this script:

```
 $url = "http://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/red-blue-design-prague.html?checkin=2012-07-07&interval=1&selected_currency=USD";
 $ckfile = tempnam ("tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

 $options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => TRUE,     // do not return headers
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => TRUE,     // do not return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "googlebot", // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => TRUE,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,        // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,        // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 3,        // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'UTF-8',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => $ckfile,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => $ckfile
  );
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  $a = curl_exec($ch);
```

but it's not getting cookies when i check `$ckfile`, can someone help, thanks

Comment: It'd be helpful to see inputs, outputs, errors...

Comment: @LeonardChallis no error, work fine but it's not getting cookies

Comment: does the cookie file contain anything?

Comment: first of all check if the request is working at all? I mean print `$a` and see if it is expected>

Comment: @Shubham i get the page but not cookies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution guys, thanks:

```
function myCurl($url)
{
    $cookie_file_path = tempnam ("tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . session_id());
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $a = curl_exec ($curl);

    return $a;
}
```